# dynamically change variable value in tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This script

```
declare @a  varchar(10), @b varchar(44)

set @b = 'abc'
set @a = @b
print @a

set @b = 'xyz'
--without doing this set @a = @b here
print @a
```

prints this :

```
abc
abc
```

Is it possible to print this somehow?

```
abc
xyz
```

Basically, I don't want to reassign @a explicitly. Maybe there is a function or something which will reassign @a? Something like REPROCESS(@a). I just don't want to reassign RHS each time, because it is a huge script on my side, just want to save some space

Actual script on my side looks like @a = 'blahblahblha 1000 lines more' + @b + 'another 1000 lines'. And then I use @a, and then I change @b to some other value and then I want to use @a again with updated @b

Comment: T-SQL does not support the concept of variable pointer/reference.

Comment: That's what I thought. But maybe there is a function or something which will reassign @a? Something like REPROCESS(@a)

Comment: Why do you need to reference the same variable with two different names? That is essentially what a pointer reference is. Just use the original name.

Comment: Because i gave an example in post above. Actual script on my side looks like @a = 'blahblahblha 1000 lines more' + @b + 'another 1000 lines'. And then I use @a, and then I change @b to some other value and then I want to use @a again with updated @b

Comment: Not sure how that indicates you couldn't just use @b. But maybe you should split a into multiples. Like a Prefix and Postfix. Then you could write the 1000 lines into prefix and the other into postfix. Easy then to update Prefix + b + Postfix. But seriously....1000 lines in a variable???

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding... the assignment operator COPIES data. It doesn't say "@b now points to the same thing @a does". It never has and never will. Again, if you want them both to refer to the same thing, just get rid of all of the @b references entirely and just use @a everywhere. If you only want one thing, only use one thing. Don't confusingly use two names for the same thing. That's just really bad/unmaintainable.

Comment: @SeanLange , I just exxagerated with 1000 lines to make it more clear. There are actually things like this 'blahblah' + @b + 'blahblah' + @c , etc. that's why I can't prefix/suffix it, I just want @a to represent updated @b value

Comment: @pmbAustin , I just wanted to be sure there is no way to imlement logic I have described. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you really want to build a template with a placeholder and then build the final string based on the template with different values for the placeholder.  So something like this (where '{b placeholder}' is any literal string that you're sure won't appear in the final string you're building).

```
set @template_a = 
            '1000 lines ' +
            ' {b placeholder} ' +
            '1000 lines';

set @b = 'Value 1';
set @a = replace( @template_a, '{b placeholder}', @b );
-- do something with @a

set @b = 'Value 2';
set @a = replace( @template_a, '{b placeholder}', @b );
-- do something with @a
```

Of course, you could factor out the set/ replace/ do something logic into a separate procedure that your script calls so you're not copying and pasting so much code.

Answer (score -2):

```
    declare @a  varchar(10), @b varchar(44)

set @b = 'abc'
set @a = 'xyz'
print 'a actual value' print @a
print 'b actual value' print @b


SET @b = substring(@a+@b,1, LEN(@a+@b) - LEN(@b));  
SET  @a =substring(@a+@b,LEN(@b)+1,LEN(@a+@b));  

print '------Swipe Result-------'
print 'a value' print @a
print 'b value' print @b
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. And you can swap variables in t-sql much simpler.